# add DataProperty in protege with Jena

Tags: jena

Anyone knows hoe to add Data Property in protege with Jena. I can easily add Object Property but for Data Property somehow doesn't work, instead of adding Properties in Data Property assertion it's adding the Annotation. Maybe something wrong with my code?

Code

```
 OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, null);


            String NS = "http://www.semanticweb.org/thato/ontologies/2012/10/9/thesis_ontology#";
            model.read(in, null);
            in.close();

            OntClass ApplicationModel = model.getOntClass(NS + "ApplicationModel");

            Individual AM20 = model.createIndividual(NS + xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("guid")+ theAttribute.getNodeValue(), ApplicationModel);

            Individual dom = model.getIndividual(NS + domainElement.getAttribute(attrDomain));
            Individual pha = model.getIndividual(NS + neededString.trim());
            Individual lev =  model.getIndividual(NS + lodElement.getAttribute(attrLOD));
            Individual typ = model.getIndividual(NS + theAttrType.getNodeValue());

            Property urlAdd =  model.createProperty(NS + "http://xxxxx.com");

            // Create Object Property
            ObjectProperty domain = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"hasDomain");
            ObjectProperty fase = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"hasPhase");
            ObjectProperty lod = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"hasLevelOfDetail");
            ObjectProperty type = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"hasType");

            model.add(AM20, domain, dom);
            model.add(AM20, fase, pha);
            model.add(AM20, lod, lev);
            model.add(AM20, type, typ);

            // Create Data Property
            DatatypeProperty url = model.createDatatypeProperty(NS + "hasURL");

            model.add(AM20, url, urlAdd );

            PrintStream p= new PrintStream("./src/thesis_ontology.owl");
            model.write(p, "RDF/XML-ABBREV", null);
            p.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess I found the problem. Hope it can help someone someday :D

the code should be like this

```
 OntClass ApplicationModel = model.getOntClass(NS + "ApplicationModel");

            Individual AM20 = model.createIndividual(NS + xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("guid")+ theAttribute.getNodeValue(), ApplicationModel);

            Individual dom = model.getIndividual(NS + domainElement.getAttribute(attrDomain));
            Individual pha = model.getIndividual(NS + neededString.trim());
            Individual lev =  model.getIndividual(NS + lodElement.getAttribute(attrLOD));
            Individual typ = model.getIndividual(NS + theAttrType.getNodeValue());


            // Create Object Property
            ObjectProperty domain = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"hasDomain");
            ObjectProperty fase = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"hasPhase");
            ObjectProperty lod = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"hasLevelOfDetail");
            ObjectProperty type = model.createObjectProperty(NS +"hasType");

            model.add(AM20, domain, dom);
            model.add(AM20, fase, pha);
            model.add(AM20, lod, lev);
            model.add(AM20, type, typ);

            // Create Data Property
            DatatypeProperty url = model.createDatatypeProperty(NS + "hasURL");

            model.add(AM20, url, "http://...");
```